# App dies coming foreground after atime without exception or stacktrace. Howto debug?

Tags: android

1. I start the app. Using it, nothing
   problem.
2. Send it to background, using phone
   for someting else.
3. If I come foeground the app again,
   it looks like it restart the
   activity, run the loader ASync task
   and then it log the following lines:

   ```
   06-22 15:45:02.611: WARN/dalvikvm(12735): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc8a0)
   06-22 15:45:02.611: WARN/dalvikvm(12735): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc8a0)
   06-22 15:45:02.621: INFO/ActivityManager(242): Process hu.ringier.nsof1.android (pid 12735) has died.
   ```

It occurs if the activity contains a gridview with remote images from web. App contains a tabwidget and every other activity works great after coming to foreground in the case if the activity is restart, but not the gridview one.

Have you any idea how can I find the problem? The logcat doesn't contain any stacktrace, just the warning and the died message.

I've searched abot this topic, but everybody got a stacktrace.

Comment: Did you try putting logs in the onStart/onResume methods to see at point it crashes ? You could also try putting a few remote images in a simple LinearLayout to see if it behaves the same. Maybe the remote images' bitmaps were unloaded, and it crashes when trying to display them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved. There was a Log call in a catch block, but I didn't log it, so it was hidden. I reviewed every cacth block add and edit all Log calls to log the exception itself. Finally I found a NPE.

Reminder: Always log catched exceptions, it doesn't hurt!